# "Laugh to myself" German equivalent

Tags: english-to-german, phrase-request

"Laughing to myself" is explained here: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/laugh-to-myself.1707033/

> Imagine a situation where you find something very amusing but it would
>   not be appropriate to laugh out loud. So you suppress all outward
>   signs of laughter, but you enjoy the amusement of the situation. You
>   would have laughed otherwise.

Is there a German equivalent to this phrase?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Duden – Das Stilwörterbuch* as well as *Duden – Das große Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache* include the expression *innerlich lachen:*

> er musste innerlich *(im Stillen)* lachen

and

> sie musste innerlich *(insgeheim, für sich)* lachen

respectively.

Accordingly, *Duden-Oxford – Großwörterbuch Englisch* translates:

> **innerlich lachen** laugh inwardly *or* to oneself

Comment: I'm not sure which one (this or tofro's answer) I should accept. Both seem to be true. Thanks to you both guys. I'm accepting the one with more votes.

Answer (score 8):

You probably would express this in German as

> Ich lachte in mich hinein

literally "laughed into myself". This is the exact expression used to express the "I won't show I'm laughing"-feeling.

Answer (score 1):

> Sich ins Fäustchen lachen

Is a somwhat hidden laughing, and the dictionary provides *laugh into ones sleeve* as English counterpart.

Comment: I'm not sure this is quite right. "Sich ins Fäustchen lachen" seems to carry a strong connotation of laughing because something bad happens to another person and you take pleasure in it. You would "ins Fäustchen lachen" if your annoying colleague struggles in a presentation, or if you see a devious plan of yours work out. So I would submit that this a very particular kind of laughing to yourself/innerlich lachen/in sich hineinlachen.